# Using group_by() to compute "grouped" ICC values

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to compute ICC values for each subject for the table below, but `group_by()` is not working as I think it should.

```
  SubID Rate1 Rate2
1     1     2     5
2     1     2     4
3     1     2     5
4     2     3     4
5     2     4     1
6     2     5     1
7     2     2     2
8     3     2     5
9     3     3     5
```

The code I am running is as follows:

```
df %>%
  group_by(SubID) %>%
  summarise(icc = DescTools::ICC(.)$results[3, 2])
```

and the output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  SubID    icc
  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 -0.247
2     2 -0.247
3     3 -0.247
```

It seems that summarise is not being applied according to groups, but to the entire dataset. I'm not sure what is going on.

dput()

```
structure(list(SubID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), Rate1 = c(2, 
2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 3), Rate2 = c(5, 4, 5, 4, 1, 1, 2, 5, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: With ICC -> you mean interclass correlation?

Comment: Actually, intraclass coefficients using DescTools package. I'll update the question

Comment: Which of these are appropriate for your setting: ICC1: One-way random-effects model.
ICC2: Two-way random-effects model. ICC3: Two-way mixed effects model?

Comment: ICC3. I'm using ```$results[3, 2])``` to "extract" the relevant ICC value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not terribly familiar with `library(DescTools)` but here is a potential solution that utilizes a `nest()` / `map()` combo:

```r
library(DescTools)
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(
  list(SubID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), 
       Rate1 = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 3), 
       Rate2 = c(5, 4, 5, 4, 1, 1, 2, 5, 5)), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L)
)

df %>%
  nest(ICC3 = -SubID) %>%
  mutate(ICC3 = map_dbl(ICC3, ~ ICC(.x)[["results"]] %>%
    filter(type == "ICC3") %>%
    pull(est)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   SubID      ICC3
#>   <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     1  2.83e-15
#> 2     2 -5.45e- 1
#> 3     3 -6.66e-16
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! This works perfect. I still don't know why group_by() doesn't work and why nest() would work. Lots of reading to do. Thanks again!